# Eclipse console apparently bugged calculating factorial of 1,000,000

Tags: java, eclipse, console

Doing some tests with a friend about the class BigInteger on Java, he made a code that prints "n: " and receive an given number to find its factorial. After some time, I tried to calculate the factorial of 1,000,000, but then (after several minutes of calculations) the console only showed a a lot of zeros, without even the print "n: " that's printed when I run the program and the "n!: " when the result is shown.

In the tests, until 300k, the code was working fine (except for the time to the calculus, but that's under expectations given the numbers). Obs.: the loop is used to separate the lines, since they only support 4096 chars

```java
public static BigInteger zero = new BigInteger("0");
    public static BigInteger one = new BigInteger("1");
    public static BigInteger minusOne = new BigInteger("-1");


    public static BigInteger fat(BigInteger n) {

        if(n.equals(zero)) {
            return new BigInteger("1");
        }

        BigInteger i = new BigInteger(n.toString());
        while(!i.equals(one)) {
            i = i.add(minusOne);
            n = n.multiply(i);
        }

        return new BigInteger(n.toString());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("n: ");
        BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(in.nextLine());
        String bigString = fat(bigInt).toString();
        int strSize = bigString.length();

        System.out.println("n! = ");

        for (int i = 0; i < strSize; i++) {
            if((i+1)%4096==0) {
                System.out.printf("%c\n",bigString.charAt(i));
            }else {
                System.out.print(bigString.charAt(i));
            }
        }

        in.close();

    }

}
```

Supposedly there was to happen some output, just not a bunch of zeros and apparently overwriting the first print. Even with large numbers such as 300k, the prints "n: " and "n!: " stayed there. There's no error's messages about Overflow or Stack Overflow. At some point I thought that the console was only showing last part of the number, but asking a friend, he said about some unknown bug of the console or Eclipse (at least for us).

Comment: What is `strSize`

Comment: What is `bigString`, and where do you invoke `fat`?

Comment: `strSize` is the size of `bigString`, and `bigString` is the converted string of `BigInteger` using `toString` method